Does nautilus require a package to show user directories in sidebar?

I installed a basic Ubuntu server, and then installed a Unity session.
The Nautilus sidebar won't show user directories.
.config/user-dirs.dirs
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"

Does Nautilus depend on a certain package such that when not installed nautilus doesn't search for XDG User Directories?
